# How to replace or edit specific lines in text file by not changing it all

Tags: c#

Im trying to replace specific lines in my text file. but when I use .Replace Method it does change all the values that containing the same value I I want to replace..

1234|Jonel, Lopez|Lasvegas Nevada|Regular Loan|10|5000|2|1000|6000|0|6000|

```
      foreach (string tmpLines in lines)
            {
                ctr++;
                if (tmpLines.Contains(search))
                {
                    ok = true;
                    break;
                }
            }


        x = lines[ctr].Split('|');
       string path = @"F:\c#\test\store.txt";
        string text = File.ReadAllText(path1);
        Console.WriteLine("[1] Add Payment\n[2] [No]");
        int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (choice == 1)
        {
              lbal = float.Parse(x[10]);
              Console.Write("Enter Amount: ");
              tpaid = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
              lbal = lbal-tpaid;
              string ball = lbal.ToString();

              text =text.Replace(x[10] ,ball);

              File.WriteAllText(path1, text);
              string paid = tpaid.ToString();

              Console.WriteLine("Your new Balance is: P{0:0.00}" , lbal);
              Console.WriteLine("Press any key to go back to Main Menu");

              Console.ReadKey();
              this.start();
        }
```

I expect only to replace the specific string in the in the lines that I have search but when I use .Replace method It does change all the values.

when I minus the value of tpaid to lbal 
it does change all the values in my text file having the same value.
I only want to replace the value of lbal which it in the x[10]

Comment: Have a look to the documentation of the method [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8). It says 'Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string.' . To exchange a part of a string with another content you need to create substrings and assemble them to a new string. In your case it may be easier to change the value in your array `x` and create a new line from the array `String.Join('|', x);`

Comment: I will not write your code, but I could try to guide you. But I need a bit more information. As far as I understand, you have a text file. What is the content. Does it only contain lines like `1234|Jonel, Lopez|Lasvegas Nevada|Regular Loan|10|5000|2|1000|6000|0|6000|`or also something else?

Comment: Yes @H.G.Sandhagen it does contains 1234|Jonel, Lopez|Lasvegas Nevada|Regular Loan|10|5000|2|1000|6000|0|6000| for or the first line .

Comment: x[0] = 1234 , x[1] = Jonel, Lopez .... x[9] = 0, x[10] = 6000
What I would like to do is to change only the value of x[9] and x[10].
Thank you @H.G.Sandhagen . whenever I used string.Replace all string having the same value will be replace...

Comment: I think you have read the file into an array of lines. So you could assign the new value and assemble a new line from it: `x[10] = ball; lines[ctr] = String.Join("|", x); File.WriteAllLines("filename",lines");`